# What does this setting for individual Chrome extensions do?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I feel like I should have been able to figure this out, but I don't understand what this switch does. It's located on the page for individual settings for every installed Google Chrome extension, wedged in between Allow in Incognito and Show in Chrome Web Store.

Translated it reads "Allow access to web addresses in the file" -- which file?

[image: "Allow access to web addresses in the file"]

I couldn't effectively google the switch's English title, since Chrome actively prevents me from changing the browser's UI language on macOS.

*Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a switch to allow the extension to access `file://` URLs. See [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings#allow_access) for details.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's a little more comprehensible than the apparently machine-translated garbage I got served.